# Scrapy with Django- Pass more information that just URL

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I'm trying to get Scrapy to run spiders for a large amount of URL's I've got stored in the DB.

The "Spiders" all work fine.

I'm having trouble getting Scrapy to "remember" which objects it is working on. The code below gets it to use the URL field to match it back into my django database.

Problem is, the URL often can change when it is accessed in the browser, so scrapy doesn't know where to put the data.

Ideally- I could just 'tell' scrapy the primary key, of the object- to remove all room for error.

```
import sys, os, scrapy, django
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

## Django init ##
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))) ## direct to where manage.py is

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'XYZDB.settings'
django.setup()

#################

## Settings ##

#queryset_chunksize = 1000

##############

    from XYZ import models
    from parsers import dj, asos, theiconic

    stores = [dj, asos, theiconic]



    parsers = dict((i.domain, i) for i in stores)

    def urls():
        for i in models.Variation.objects.iterator():
            yield i.link_original if i.link_original else i.link


    class Superspider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = 'Superspider'

        start_urls = urls()

        def parse(self, response):
            for i in parsers:
                if i in response.url:
                    return parsers[i].parse(response)


    ## Reference - models
    '''
    Stock_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'In Stock'),
        (2, 'Low Stock'),
        (3, 'Out of Stock'),
        (4, 'Discontinued'),
    )
    '''

    class ProductPipeline:
        def process_item(self, item, spider):
            var = models.Variation.objects.get(link_original=item['url'])
            size = models.Size.objects.get(variation=var)
            if item['stock'] != models.Stock.objects.filter(size=size)[0]:
                models.Stock(size=size, stock=item['stock']).save()

            if int(item['price']) != int(models.Price.objects.filter(variation=var)):
                models.Price(variation=var, price=item['price']).save()
            return


    if __name__ == '__main__':

        process = CrawlerProcess({
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',  
           'ITEM_PIPELINES': {'__main__.ProductPipeline': 1,},
           'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.4
           })

        process.crawl(Superspider)
        process.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of scrapy's [response.meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html) attribute. Replace the definition of start_urls with the routine `start_requests(self)` where you can `yield Request(your url, meta={'pk': primary key})`. You can then access the meta data in the parse() routine using `item['pk'] = response.meta['pk']`. [start_requests() docs.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html)